# Selecting column doesn't exist in Link Table

Tags: mysql

I wanted to select specified column from my master table that doesn't exist in my link table. But it gives me a empty row even the `id` still doesn't exist in link table.

```
SELECT faculty_mt.firstName FROM faculty_mt
INNER JOIN section_settings_lt ON section_settings_lt.adviser_id = faculty_mt.faculty_id
WHERE faculty_mt.faculty_id NOT IN (SELECT adviser_id FROM section_settings_lt);
```

I tried to changed from `SELECT adviser_id` to `SELECT session_id` but this gives me a value that exist in my link table.

**faculty_mt**

`faculty_id  |  firstName
     15           Daisy
     16           Orange`

**section_settings_lt**

`section_id | adviser_id |  session_id
    1           15              1`

Output should be:

`firstName
  Orange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    faculty_mt.firstName
FROM
    faculty_mt
LEFT JOIN
    section_settings_lt
ON
    section_settings_lt.adviser_id = faculty_mt.faculty_id
WHERE
    section_settings_lt.adviser_id is NULL;
```